# reference for the shloka - sada idam utthītam sada iti che na nūh tarakhatam

Tags: vedas, puranas, mantras, reference-request, shloka

Can someone assist me in finding the reference for the shloka

> sada idam utthītam sada iti che na nūh tarakhatam

> सद इदं उथीतम सद इति चे न नूह तरकहतम

potential meaning of each word based on my limited understanding

```
- सद (sada): always, eternal, ever
- इदं (idam): this
- उथीतम् (utthītam): arisen, emerged
- इति (iti): thus, in this way
- चे (che): and
- न (na): not
- नूह (nūh): certainly not, never
- तरकहतम् (tarakhatam): the greatest, the ultimate
```

Comment: Sounds a lot like something someone made up, the grammar is wrong, the Chhandas is wrong... heck even the spelling is wrong . I think what you're trying to say is: "सदा इदँ उत्थितँ सदा इति चे न नूः तरखतम्"? But even then, it doesn't really mean anything. Did you listen to this in passing and is this your recollection of it? I'm quite curious to see where you've found this "shloka"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**सत इदं उत्थितं सदिति चेन्ननु तर्कहतं ।**
व्यभिचरति क्व च क्व च मृषा न तथोभययुक् ।
व्यवहृतये विकल्प इषितोऽन्धपरम्परया ।
भ्रमयति भारती त उरुवृत्तिभिरुक्थजडान् ॥ ३६ ॥

10.87.36 from Bhagavata Mahapurana.

Translation :

> If it is argued that this (objective) universe is real in that it has evolved from the Real (God), this proposition is surely disproved by critical examination. The fact of an effect following the nature of its cause varies in certain cases (as for example a son is found to be different from his father); while in some (other) cases the evolute of a real substance is known to be false (just as the perception of a serpent following from a real substance, viz., a rope is false). (It may be objected here that it is not the rope alone but the rope coupled with ignorance which is responsible for its being mistaken for a snake. Our reply to this objection is that) the world (too) is a product of both (viz., Brahma and Avidya); hence it is not real. (If the world is held to be real because it serves our purpose and discharges some function too, our reply is that) for explaining worldly transactions the illusory nature of the universe is (on the other hand) more welcome (to us); for worldly transactions will be carried on by blindly following past traditions. Your word (in the shape of Vedic texts declaring the reward of ritual acts as real) deludes by its manifold powers of expressing, indicating or suggesting a meaning (only) those dullwitted persons who have been blinded by their excessive faith in (Vedic) rituals.

[Source](https://archive.org/details/bhagavatapuranagitapress_201907/page/n1359/mode/2up?view=theater)